# System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null in class

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

In **web.config** file i have :

```
  <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="connectionString" connectionString="Data Source=Server; Initial Catalog=DB; Persist Security Info=true; User ID=****; Password=****" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I try to reed this connection string in the class :

```
var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

But I get this error :

> System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get
>   returned null

Comment: What's your .NET version??

Comment: have you ensured that the config file is placed correctly at the directory which you're running the application? in the executing directory does there exist an ApplicationName.exe.config file?

Comment: I use .Net Core 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest in .net core apps use **appsettings.json** and read connectionString from it :

```
   static class class
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;

    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
         var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

         Configuration = builder.Build();
         var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:connectionString"];

    }
}
```

**appsettings.json** :

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "connectionString": "............."
  }
}
```